# Converting integer to star rating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Firstly here is my file structure

#### application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def show_stars(review)
    image_tag review.rating
  end
end
```

#### Controller: customers_controller.rb

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_admin
  # reviews
  def reviews
    @reviews = Review.all
  end
end
```

#### view: reviews.haml

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{ :style => "width:8%" } Ratings
      %tbody
        - @reviews.each do |review|
          %tr
            %td{ :style => "text-align:center" }= review.rating.show_stars
```

I have `rating` setup as a integer in my schema and what I am trying to do is convert the integer into a star image via the application helper. However when i try using my method i end up getting

```
undefined method `show_stars' for 4:Fixnum // 4 is my rating value
```

What am I missing here? I'm just starting out on ruby so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method accepts rating (signature `show_stars(review)`), so use it properly: change `review.rating.show_stars` to `show_stars(review)`

Comment: Derp, that makes since but I am still getting the same error `undefined method rating for 4:Fixnum` is it because its a integer and not a string?

Comment: Maybe restart the server, it cant be the same error.

Comment: Yea still the same `undefined method show_stars` is now `undefined method rating for 4:Fixnum` (calling error on the helper instead)

Comment: Yeah, you take rating 2 times, first in view, then in helper.

Comment: Hey hey hey! nice! Thanks a lot man I'm always just a few steps off with ruby